# How to use stored procedure with Azure Mobile .Net backend service?

Tags: .net, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile service to retrieve data from my SQL table.
If I use default `Query()` as a return type then I am able to fetch all the records in my mobile App:

This works fine:

```
// GET tables/SaleItem
 public IQueryable<SaleItem> GetAllSaleItems()
 {
      return Query();
  }
```

In my mobile App, I am using Azure Offline Sync, so with the above implementation calling `PullAsync()` is executing properly.

Now if I change my backend to retrieve data through Stored Procedure as below than calling to `PullAsync()` going into deadlock and not able to execute code after that.

```
public IQueryable<SaleItem> GetAllSaleItems()
{
   var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

   var command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetSalesData", connection);
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   connection.Open();

   var saleItems = new List<SaleItem>();

   using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (reader.Read())
      {
        var brand = new SaleItem
         {
           Id = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
           Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
           Description = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
           Price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(3)),
           ImageUrl = reader.GetValue(4).ToString(),
           Version = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.GetValue(5).ToString()),
           CreatedAt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now),
           UpdatedAt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now),
        };
     saleItems.Add(brand);
     }
    }

   connection.Close();
   var items = saleItems.AsQueryable();
   return items;
}
```

In Postman I can see that data is coming properly.

Am I doing a wrong conversion for `Version` property? Because that is the only field which has different values in both the responses.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the stored proc (minus any sensitive information)? If you are using Azure SQL as the database, then https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/04/19/deadlock-analysis-for-sql-azure-database/ may help you get more information on which queries are causing the deadlock.

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT Actually I created a sample project for getting familiar with Azure Offline Sync. In my database I only have 2 tables and each table have max 5 records. I wrote SP to fetch record from both the table, that's it, nothing complex. Also I am getting response in Postman. So the issue is from Mobile end or from Backend am not sure about it.

Comment: Do the models in the mobile app match the two tables in the database or the single dataset that comes from the stored proc?

Comment: Yes, models are same in both Mobile App and the one sent by stored procedure.

Comment: For reference you can use [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files) Github sample. In Service project replace `new Query()` with stored procedure in Get request of `TodoItemController`

Comment: One more point, If I use `IMobileServiceTable` instance than PullAsync is working, but if I change it to `IMobileServiceSyncTable` then it's not working.

Comment: Got it. I will see if I can reproduce the issue.